# Encryption into a 32-bit string in Unicode (UCS-16) format by MD5 algorithm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, md5

I have this code to generate MD5 Hash in UTF-8 format :

```
const char* str = [clearPassword  UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
}

return ret;
```

But my requirement needs to have 32-bit Unicode Hash.

lets say the string is "admin". using my code, I'll have "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" which is wrong.

I used some online generators to get unicode hash and I got "19a2854144b63a8f7617a6f225019b12" which exactly what I want.

Which part of my code needs to be changed?

Comment: I get your first result using `md5 -s` and using this generator: http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is UTF-8 MD5 hash I guess. What I need is Unicode format of MD5 Hash (the second value that I mentioned)

Comment: Oh, you want a hash of the UTF-16 encoded string. I gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSData *utf16data = [clearPassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5([utf16data bytes], [utf16data length], result);


NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
}

return ret;
```